# How to open PubMed's .nbib files

Tags: r, database, import, converters, bibtex

I'm struggling to open a **.nbib** file extracted from ERIC (MEDLINE/PubMed-style format). The file can be exported [here](https://eric.ed.gov/?q=%22working%20memory%22%20AND%20%22academic%20success%22). I'm trying to use the [rbibutils](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rbibutils/rbibutils.pdf) package, but I'm struggling with that. Can anybody help me?

- Code:

```
### LOAD PACKAGES

library(tidyverse)
library(rbibutils)

### READ DATA

bib_data <- readBib(file = "data/screening/fridayTest.nbib", 
                    encoding = 'UTF-8',
                    texChars = "convert",
                    informat = "nbib")

## filename: fridayTest.nbib
```

- ERROR:

```
Error in readBib(file = "data/screening/fridayTest.nbib", encoding = "UTF-8",  : 
  length(list(...)) == 0 is not TRUE
```

- I'm open to using other packages as well, I just need to open this file. Ultimately, I want to convert the file to a tibble or a dataframe. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `revtools::read_bibliography()` to get a data frame of all exported bibliographies. I downloaded the first 10 citations from your link, and just pointed the function to the file path of the .nbib file:

```
cites <- revtools::read_bibliography("~/Downloads/ERIC2023-08-25_09.42.28.nbib")
```

Output of `cites` (put as picture since so much texts makes it hard to paste here)

[image]